# mouseenter function only works vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace one image (closed bag) to another (open bag) using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions. For some reason it only works when I leave the mouse vertically, but not horizontally. I suspect it has to do with the length of the image but I inspected it and it was not the issue. Here is my code:

```js
$("#tumi_front").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#tumi_front").hide();
  $("#tumi_open").show();
});
$("#tumi_open").mouseleave(function() {
  // alert('leave');
  $("#tumi_front").show();
  $("#tumi_open").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="tumi_front" src="tumi_front.png" alt="yolo front" height="40%" width="40%" />
<img id="tumi_open" src="tumi_open.png" alt="yolo open" height="30%" width="30%" " style="display: none " />
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: When you leave `tumi_open` on the side, it shows `tumi_front` briefly. But the mouse is now inside `tumi_front`, so it hides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're setting your two different images to have a different height and width. Your front image is at `40%` and your second is at `30%`. So when you try to hover outside of your smaller image, it triggers the hover onto the larger image, and then hides your image over again, causing the glitch.

**[Your code (40% 30% broken)](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfdjzqhm/1/)**

A better solution for this would be to give both your images the same class and toggle the images. This will fix the hover issue you are having with the different sized images, and it is more efficient.

**jQuery**

```
$(".double-img").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
  $(".double-img").toggle();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfdjzqhm/4/)**

[**My code (40% 30% fixed)**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfdjzqhm/3/)

Comment: I don't understand.  What difference does the image sizing have?

Comment: So since 1 image is smaller than the other, when you hover outside of the small image it triggers the enter and leave event for the larger image, which makes your image flash, and then appear stuck on the smaller image. It works when you approach it from the top, because the larger image is at the same point and doesn't overflow there.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation. I did put image sizing inside style

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 1 image (image sprite) and do a `background-position` with css on `:hover`. No jquery required!